# How to align title to centre and texts to left in same container?

Tags: css, react-native

Hi I am learning react native. I am trying to create a registration form. I that I need the title in the centre top and all the label fields to the left . Following is my code.

```
 <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    scrollEnabled >
  <View style={styles.fieldsContainer}>
  <View>
  <Text style={styles.headline}>Personal Info</Text>
  </View>
 <Text></Text>
```

and css

```
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
  },
fieldsContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    margin:10,
    paddingTop:30,
    paddingLeft:20,
    backgroundColor: '#D3D3D3',
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textLabelsStyle: {
fontSize:34,
fontWeight:'bold',
color:'black',
  },
  headline: {
    textAlign: 'center', 
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18,

    marginTop: 0,
    width: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
```

The problem I am facing is that I cannot get the title to the center and field label to left at same time.

Comment: Why don't you give style to the `View` that your wrapped your `headline` like `style={{justifyContent:'center'}}`

Comment: please share a sample UI design of what you want to achieve

Comment: @Ron https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Atbc4zwzSCE
Please see this link and see the end, I just want that registration text at the centre.

Comment: Are you saying personal info text is not sitting in the center??

Answer (score 0):

**Add alignSelf to center.**

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
    scrollEnabled >
  <View style={styles.fieldsContainer}>
  <View style={{alignSelf:'center'}}>
  <Text style={styles.headline}>Personal Info</Text>
  </View>
 <Text></Text>
```